# How do I shave off time from my genetic algorithm sudoku solver?

Tags: numpy, performance, optimization, genetic-algorithm, sudoku

I have created a sudoku solver using a genetic algorithm, although it is very slow. The slowest of step seems to be calculating fitness and finding the best fitness in my population. The code for this looks like this:

```
#2.80 seconds
fitness_list = [fitness_function(individual, fixed_indices) for individual in current_generation]
fitness_list_indices = np.argsort(fitness_list, kind='heapsort')
fitness_over_time.append(fitness_list[fitness_list_indices[0]]) #append for plot
```

where I have defined fitness_function(individual, fixed_indices) as:

```
def fitness_function(puzzle, fixed_indices):
    return len(remove_fixed_indices(sudoku_validifier(puzzle), fixed_indices))
```

, remove_fixed_indices() as:

```
def remove_fixed_indices(badboard, fixedboard):   
    """Removes fixed indices from list. fix = list of fixed indices as '[(2,5), (3,7), ...].
        bad = list of new boardnumbers as [(3,7,9), (2,5,9), ...]
        where first two integers are indices and third is their number
    """                                  
    return [badboard[x] for x in range(len(badboard)) if badboard[x][:-1] not in fixedboard]
```

, sudoku_validifier(puzzle) as:

```
def sudoku_validifier(puzzle):      
    """returns all duplicates of sudoku board and the corresponding
        2d-index of each duplicate. Return example of 1 duplicate:
        '[(3, 5), (6, 5)]'. 2 duplicates: '[(3, 5), (3, 8), (2, 8), (3, 8)]'.
        Multiple of the same index occurs because duplicates in both row/column and/or square
    """
    puzzle = np.array(puzzle)       
    duplicate_indices = []          
                                     
    for i in range(9):
        for dup in return_duplicate_index(puzzle[i]):
            for dup_index in dup:
                duplicate_indices.append((i, dup_index))

    for j in range(9):
        for dup in return_duplicate_index(puzzle[:,j]):
            for dup_index in dup:
                duplicate_indices.append((dup_index, j))

    mesh = (0,3,6)
    for k, l in np.nditer([mesh, mesh]):
        list = puzzle[k:k+3,l:l+3].flatten()
        for dup in return_duplicate_index(list):
            for dup_index in dup:
                duplicate_indices.append((dup_index//3 + k, dup_index%3 + l))
    return duplicate_indices
```

, and lastly return_duplicate_index() as

```
def return_duplicate_index(list):
    """#returns index of all duplicates except for 0-duplicates, input: list"""
    dup = {}
    for i,x in enumerate(list):
        dup.setdefault(x,[]).append(i)
    duplicate_index = [x for i,x in dup.items() if len(x) > 1 and i > 0]
    return duplicate_index
```

. fixed_indices is a list of the indices of the already determined numbers of the sudoku board, before solving. I know it's a lot of iterating too. Is it possible to make it faster anyway?
It can solve this sudoku board I found on Codewars:

```
easy =  [
        [5,3,0,0,7,0,0,0,0],
        [6,0,0,1,9,5,0,0,0],
        [0,9,8,0,0,0,0,6,0],
        [8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3],
        [4,0,0,8,0,3,0,0,1],
        [7,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,6],
        [0,6,0,0,0,0,2,8,0],
        [0,0,0,4,1,9,0,0,5],
        [0,0,0,0,8,0,0,7,9]
        ]
```

[Example of solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GhBr.png) Full code: https://github.com/Mangokalsong/GeneticAlgorithmSudokuSolver

I've also been trying to change the parameters, but to no success.

Comment: As there is only one feasible solution, I would expect all of these types of heuristics to be slow.

Comment: One off-topic but important advice: please don't use python keywords as variable names. You are using `list` as a variable. As for your whole code, there is a lot to go through, but since you are mainly working on an `NxN` grid/matrix and some intermediate arrays/lists, it should be possible to speed your code up by using [numba](https://numba.pydata.org). It will take a lot of work though.